# How to remove apostrophe when provide custom value from "custom value input field"?

Tags: sass, apostrophe

First i added default value for opacitiy in `_colors.scss` like that :

```
// Header
$header-overlay-opacity: 0.5 !default;
```

Then, i created "input field" for opacity of overlay effect by header.yaml :

```
name: Header Styles
description: Page Surround section styles
type: section
overlay-opacity:
      type: input.text
      label: Overlay Opacity
      description: 'Provide the opacity of the linear gradient overlay.'
```

It's providing posibility to change default opacity value that i declared as "opacity : 0.5;" in `_colors.scss`

Then i added codes in `_header.scss` file for styling like that:

```
#header {
opacity: $header-overlay-opacity;
}
```

If i don't provide any value from input field, its adding 0.5 opacity without apostrophe for overlay as default from `_colors.scss`

The result in chrome developer console is :  `opacity: 0.5;`

It's works fine.

But if i provide custom value from input field somethings like `Overlay Opacity : 0.3`, then its adding **apostrophe** for code of opacity. The result of code as strike-through code like that: `opacity: '0.3';`

I mean it's adding **apostropheted** `' '` value for value of opacity. By the cause, it's not working. How i can disable to **apostrophe** `' '` for value of opacity field?

I tried all of several input types like:

```
input.text
input.number
input.selectize
input.keyvalue
```

But still don't works.

I have just one longest way to solve it like that.
Create select.selectize type field then add all of opacity options in it :

```
 - 0
 - 0.1
 - 0.2
 - 0.3
 - 0.4
 - 0.5
 - 0.6
 - 0.7
 - 0.8
 - 0.9
 - 1
```

Then use this way in `header.scss` :

```
@if $header-img-overlay == '0' {
                    &:before {
                    opacity: 0;}
}
@if $header-img-overlay == '0.1' {
                    &:before {
                    opacity: 0.1;}
}
@if $header-img-overlay == '0.2' {
                    &:before {
                    opacity: 0.2;}
}
@if $header-img-overlay == '0.3' {
                    &:before {
                    opacity: 0.3;}
}
.
.
.
.
.
```

But i don't want to use this long way. How i can use **no apostropheted** `' '` value for `opacity : ;` field that created from custom value input field?

In same way, the custom color values can be `background : #fff;` as **no apostropheted** `''`  value that coming from $header-background input field.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The working solution is use opacity: `unquote($header-img-opc-opt);` instead `opacity: $header-img-opc-opt;`